# Show that $Q^T\cdot A \cdot Q $ is Hessenberg matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix, $x$ is a $n$ dimensional vector. Let $K=[x ; Ax; A^2x;...; A^{n-1}x]$ and suppose that $det(K) $ is not equal to zero. Let $K=Q\cdot R$ be the $QR$-factorisation of the matrix $K$. Show that $Q^T*A*Q$ is a Hessenberg matrix. Can someone help me with this problem. Thanks!

Comment: I presume then that we are talking about $n\times n$ matrices and $x$ is an $n$-dimensional vector?

Comment: Yes indeed, I will edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace $x$ with $x' = Q^Tx$ and $A$ with $A' = Q^TAQ$. Then the new $K'$ is just $Q^TK = R$, which is upper-triangular. In particular

- $x'$ has to have $0$ in all coordinates but the first.
- $A'$ of a vector with $0$ for all coordinates but the first, is a vector with $0$ for all coordinates but the first 2.
- $A'$ of a vector with $0$ for all coordinates but the first 2, is a vector with $0$ for all coordinates but the first 3.
- etc.